# Rails Can't verify CSRF token authenticity ajax with X-CSRF-TOKEN header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, csrf

I try to register a service worker endpoint in my database but when I send my post data with fetch the app raise an error.

I want to keep the csrf verification. Do you see something wrong ?

```
            var ready;

            ready = function(){
              if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
               console.log('Service Worker is supported');
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(reg) {

                 reg.pushManager.subscribe({
                     userVisibleOnly: true
                 }).then(function(sub) {
                     console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
                     console.log(sub);
                     var token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
            console.log(token);

                     return fetch('/register_endpoint', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                      'Content-type': 'application/json',
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                      endpoint: sub.endpoint,
                      authenticity_token: token

                    })
                  });
                 });


               }).catch(function(err) {
                 console.log('Erreur -> ', err);
               });
              }

            };



            $(document).ready(ready);
            $(document).on('page:load',ready);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ajax` or `fetch` Both works in your case.

```
let token = function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))};

$.ajax({ url: URL,
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: token,
  data: 'someData=' + someData,
  success: function(response) {
    $('#someDiv').html(response);
  }
});
```

Or:

```
return fetch( URL, {
 method: 'post',
 headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({endpoint: sub.endpoint}),
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})
```

Comment: @lokhi I do not know how `fetch` works in your case, but `$ajax` authenticity token actually header being included with `beforeSend`method. 

BeforeSend: This event, which is triggered before an Ajax request is started, allows you to modify the XMLHttpRequest object (setting additional headers, if need be.)

Comment: Downvoted as switching to a different library isn't really a good solution. The answer by Omar Rayward is the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that the session cookie is not being sent if `credentials` is not specified as an option within `fetch`.

`credentials` has [3 possible values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials):

- `omit` -> Doesn't send cookies
- `same-origin` -> Only send cookies if the URL is on the same origin as the calling script
- `include` -> Always send cookies, even for cross-origin calls

So this should probably work:

```
return fetch('/register_endpoint', {
 method: 'post',
 headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({endpoint: sub.endpoint}),
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) more info about the native fetch api.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The reason why this is needed is because the CSRF token is also stored in the Rails session (which by default uses cookies). For the request to be valid, the CSRF token passed in the header must match the value in the session.

Comment: I couldn't make this to work because fetch() lowercases all the header keys. And rails server cannot tell that "x-csrf-token" contains the info for "X-CSRF-Token".

Answer (score 0):

This is also not working for me so I have override this **verified_request?** method CsrfToken

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :verified_request?

  protected

  def verified_request?
      return true if request.get?
      if respond_to?(:valid_authenticity_token?, true)
        super || valid_authenticity_token?(session, URI.unescape(request.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] || "") )
      else
        super || form_authenticity_token == URI.unescape(request.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] || "")
      end
    end
end
```